# command line arguments for two text files

Tags: c#

I need help on how I can open the following two text files, answerfile and outputfile, using command line arguments:

```
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\AnswerFile.txt");
    System.IO.StreamWriter fileWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\outputFile.txt");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(line);
        fileWriter.WriteLine(line);
        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();
    fileWriter.Close();
    System.Console.WriteLine("There were {0} lines.", counter);
    // Suspend the screen.
    System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Either use your `string[] args` that you got from `main` or use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(args[0]);
System.IO.StreamWriter fileWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(args[1]);
```

or if no `string[] args` is present on Main function, in that case

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

assuming that your program is named `prog.exe`

and is started as `C:\>prog.exe infile.txt outfile.txt`

Comment: That's assuming that this is in `main` or is in a function that is passed `args`. I would suggest suggesting the use of `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` as an alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by started as c:\...? should I include that as is in the code? like this: c:\>readline.exe AnswerFile.txt outputfile.txt ??

Comment: PaRiMaL is talking about how you *run* your program.  You can also specify command line arguments in the project settings if you're running from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try following changes in these two lines of your code rest will be same.

```
//System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\AnswerFile.txt");
//System.IO.StreamWriter fileWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\outputFile.txt");

if (args.Length < 2)
{
    throw new Exception("File(s) not provided.");
}

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(args[0]);
System.IO.StreamWriter fileWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(args[1]);
```

Comment: But would it still know that I want it to access the answerfile and the output file? Even though I call it as args[0] and args[1]?

Answer (score 0):

Compile you code (Consider it creates a file say demo.exe). Now open command prompt and go to that location where demo.exe present. Put following commad.

```
demo.exe "c:\AnswerFile.txt" "C:\outputFile.txt"
```

Hope it will work.